# Dynamically update variables used in a For statement in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to update the list used in the for loop statement as it is being appended with new values within the loop.I know this code wont update the list but I am not able to find a way to do so. I hope to required output might explain it better

## INPUT

```
list=[1,2,3]
count=0
for x in list:
    if int(len(list))>10:
        break
    else:
        count=count+1
        x=x+10
        if x>3:
            list=list+[x]

print "list = %r" %list
print "count = %r" %count
```

## OUTPUT

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13]
count = 3
```

## Required OUTPUT

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31]
count = 10
```

Comment: Avoid using the key word `list` as a variable name, ugly and dangerous...

Comment: It is working fine for me. Output is `list = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32]` and `count = 8`(which is the correct output for the given code as opposed to the required output according to OP).

Comment: @Rahul Looks like this is version dependent, would be helpful to know which python versions you are using.

Comment: Using Python 2.7.11 here. What version are you using?

Comment: Mutating a collection while iterating over it is almost never a good idea.  The answer is almost certainly to create a new list containing only the values you want.  (After you've been using Python for a while, you'll find yourself using generator functions for almost every situation like this, but for beginners, just create a new list.)

Comment: Also, it's not clear what `count` is supposed to be a count _of_.  Do you just want the length of the new list (in which case `len(output_list)` is all you need), or something else?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick replies

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `while` loop instead of a `for`, which saves the need of the `break` keyword :

```
l=[1,2,3]
count = len(l) # There are already len(l) elements in the list
pos = 0

while len(l) < 10:

    count += 1

    x = l[pos]

    l.append(x+10)

    pos += 1

print "list = %r" %l
print "count = %r" %count
```

Which gives the output :

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31]
count = 10
```

Also, you can notice that i renamed the `list` variable to `l`, to prevent any confusion between the type `list` and the variable itself.

I used [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add elements at the end of the list.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

two problems here:

first: the `if x>3:` test. (Why did you include that?)

second when you have a `for` statement, it loops on the values present initially only.

This should work:

```
l = [1,2,3]
count = 0
while len(l) < 10:
    l.append(l[count]+10)
    count += 1
```